# Show tcp stream using HTML

Tags: php, html, tcp, video-streaming, gstreamer

I want to stream the video of a webcam using gstreamer to the network. On the embedded Linux environment I have gstreamer running with the following command:

```
gst-launch mfw_v4lsrc ! vpuenc codec=12 ! multipartmux ! tcpserversink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234 sync=false
```

I can receive this stream with VLC player using `tcp://127.0.0.1:1234`. That works perfect.

Now I want to show the video in my webbrowser. I figured out that I cannot use the HTML5 video tag. This shows a black image.
Also using `http://127.0.0.1:1234` will show the video control, but no video.

Therefore I try to use PHP to receive the stream and to pusblish them with the webserver. I implemented the example on the php website:

```
<?php
$fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://www.example.com:80", $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 1024);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

This only prints the received bytes of the stream. But I do not know how to encode the stream to show the video. How can I convert the stream into a video showing on the webpage?

Comment: I've updated Kurento sources link - they are actually using GStreamer now, yet I didn't figure out how to use it standalone.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved the problem by using WebRTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most browser-compliant way is

**WebRTC streaming**

Currently, I'm still looking for a good way to do it.

- I'm expecting a lot from [OpenWebRTC](http://www.openwebrtc.io/), but didn't manage to build it yet.
- There is a [webrtcsink](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-elements/tree/master/src/gst-plugins) GStreamer plugin in Kurento media server, but I didn't figure out if it can be used on itself yet. One can [install and try it on Ubuntu 13.10 or 14.04](https://launchpad.net/~kurento/+archive/ubuntu/kurento); building from source takes a lot of setup and exploration.
- There's a [Janus](http://the.randomengineer.com/2014/05/21/lightweight-live-video-in-a-webpage-with-gstreamer-and-webrtc/comment-page-1/) server.
- Probably, a way more options.

**OR**

You can use a streaming server to either to:

- proxy a RTMP stream (originally by Adobe, opensourced now);
- distribute HTTP Live Streaming (hls);
- distribute MPEG-DASH HTTP stream.

I personally use [nginx RTMP module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module). There are other options like Wowza.

**RTMP**

There are `flvmux ! rtmpsink` in GStreamer.

On a page, you will need a Flash player. JWPlayer worked for me.

**HLS**

Stream it `with nginx-rtmp-module` or you can toy with this little [http-launch](https://coaxion.net/blog/2013/10/streaming-gstreamer-pipelines-via-http/) program.

HLS will work natively on iOS and Android, but not on a desktop (not without a Javascript client).

**DASH**

Stream it with `nginx-rtmp-module`.

DASH stream is supported by HTML5 in some browsers - depending on codecs used, situation is pretty bad - plus you will need a dash.js player for that.

Both HLS and DASH need a Source Media Extensions support in a desktop browser (now in Chrome, Safari and Opera), and a Javascript player to use one.

Browser support for some of the key technologies and codecs: https://html5test.com/compare/feature/webrtc-webrtc/video-mediasource/video-h264/video-webmvp8.html